# Ruby variable assignment

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

Can someone explain this behavior:

```
a = b = c = 1, 2, 3 
a # => [1, 2, 3]
b # => 1
c # => 1
```

In the assignment `a = b = c = 1, 2, 3`, the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` should be assigned `[1, 2, 3]`. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being confused

```
a=b=c=1,2,3
```

is actually:

```
a = (b = c = 1), 2, 3
```

that leaves

```
c = 1 # => 1 
b = c # => 1 
a = 1,2,3 # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Yep just discovered this myself by playing around in the console

Comment: What is the reason behind this behaviour, we know that its `a = (b = c = 1), 2, 3`, even if we are taking more than 3 no. of variables, the behaviour is same!

Comment: @RSB sorry I dont get your comment. OP is not doing parallel assignment. He is assigning one object to other. That leaves `b` with same object as `c` but the same object cannot be assigned to `a` as  OP has given `2,3` after the assignment (which btw is parallel assignment). I guess my expansion clearly explain that?

Comment: @shivam I don't think there is any parallel assignment as there are no multiple comma separated variables. Its simply assigning a the entire array.

Comment: @SachinPrasad you're correct. no parallel assignment in the end. I was mistaken at that point. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain why is this happening

@shivam [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182639/477037) the question, but adding some parentheses might clarify things even more.

```
a = b = c = 1, 2, 3
```

is interpreted as:

```
a = [(b = (c = 1)), 2, 3]
```

The expression is evaluated in this order:

```
           c = 1
      b = (     )
a = [(           ), 2, 3]
```

> the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` should be assigned `[1, 2, 3]`

To get the expected result, you could write:

```
a = b = c = [1, 2, 3]
```

which is interpreted as:

```
a = (b = (c = [1, 2, 3]))
```

and evaluated in this order:

```
          c = [1, 2, 3]
     b = (             )
a = (                   )
```

Comment: Why is the expression remainder `,2,3` left until evaluating `a`, and not before, when evaluating `c`, or even `b` (although that would make even less sense)? I fail to see the logic behind it. Don't *normal* languages evaluate the rvalue first and then assign it to the lvalue(s)?

Comment: @BorisB. maybe this is misleading. I just wanted to point out that the first assignment is `c = 1`, followed by `b = ...` and finally `a = ...`

Comment: @BorisB. actually, this is correct. The whole array is the *rvalue*, but the elements within the array literal are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score -2):

To do what you are talking about you should do as follow:

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
    p a #=> 1
    p b #=> 2
    p c #=> 3
```